# Скролл сверху и снизу блока

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Подскажите? может кто знает как сделать горизонтальный скролл сверху и снизу блока одновременно, может у кого есть готовый код???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно должно получаться что-то [в этом роде](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BEFd2/1/), но тут надо бы доработать до ума, на что у меня сейчас нет времени.

Answer (score 0):

overflow:scroll
[Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

[UPD] 
Для двух одновременно можно использовать, например это [Кастом скролл](http://csscode.ru/test/scroll/), [Источник](http://habrahabr.ru/post/164141/)

Comment: @ROOT ты не совсем понял вопрос!

Comment: Да, дочитал, что нужно одновременно. Тогда нужно только javasript решение. Пример тут http://csscode.ru/test/scroll/

Comment: так а где там два скрола?? мне нужно два горизонтальных один сверху другой снизу

Comment: Вот так вот http://floomby.ru/s1/BaEne5